# C# How to use Enums like in C++?

Tags: c#, enums

In C++ I can have an enum like this

```
enum RoomItems {
  WALL = 0,
  EMPTY = 1,
  START = 2,
  LOCK = 3,
  EXIT = 4
};
```

And then use it in the code like this:

```
Room temp = new Room({ WALL, START, LOCK });
```

Here's how I would do that in C# (to my current knowledge)

```
Room temp = new Room(new List<RoomItems>() { RoomItems.WALL, RoomItems.START, RoomItems.LOCK });
```

This is quite annoying when you have for example, large lists of these "items". In the C++ version of this program of mine, the rooms can have Item counts in the 20's, and while in my C++ code it still looks quite neat, in the C# version of my program, the code lines would just be way too long.

Is there a way I can use enums without using their name (as in without RoomItems.*), and if not, then is there a better alternative?

Comment: what is Room about? what are you trying to do?

Comment: You could add line breaks. (Sorry C# is verbose)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for, being able to reference members of a type without specifying the type name, is supported starting with C# 6.0, through the [using static directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static).

In the file where your enum is being referenced:

```
using static YourNameSpace.RoomItems;

[...]

var temp = new Room(new [] { WALL, START, LOCK });
```

(This passes the items as an array instead of a List, so make sure your Room constructor accepts `IEnumerable<RoomItem>`. You can use `.ToList()` if you absolutely need to use list-specific features in the constructor.)

Comment: I think this might be what I was looking for, so I'll accept this as the answer for now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can using [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) instead of passing a list. Assuming the `Room` constructor is defined as:

```
public Room(params RoomItems[] items){ ... }
```

you can then do:

```
Room temp = new Room(WALL, START, LOCK );
```

Note that a `static` import (AKA, [`using static` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static)) of `RoomItems` is needed otherwise you'll have to prefix the full name as in:

```
Room temp = new Room(RoomItems.WALL, RoomItems.START, RoomItems.LOCK );
```

Comment: This seems like it would be a good solution, but one problem is: I have some Room constructors that take two Lists of RoomItems, which wouldn't work with params.

Comment: @Magicrafter13Gaming why wouldn't it? overload the constructors.

Comment: @Aomine Imagine 2 distinct lists, how would you distinguish between them?

Comment: @DavidG sorry if I am being stubborn today, can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Sure, imagine OP already has a constructor like this `public Room(List<RoomItem> roomItems1, List<RoomItem> roomItems2)`

Comment: @DavidG right I see what you mean, this wasn't part of the requirement at the time of posting hence didn't put any thinking into it. but will think of a solution when I have time and see if the answer can be improved.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor for example assuming`RoomItems` is located in `Project.Models`  then you'd do `using static Project.Models.RoomItems;` in which case you can do `new Room(WALL, START, LOCK );` without having to write `RoomItems.WALL, RoomItems.START,` etc.

Comment: @Aomine not sure what you mean by Project.Models

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your room with a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers):

```
using static YourNameSpace.RoomItems;

var temp = new Room() { WALL, START, LOCK };
```

if your room class implements IEnumerable and exposes a public add method:

```
class Room : IEnumerable<RoomItems>
{
    List<RoomItems> items = new List<RoomItems>();

    public void Add(RoomItems item)
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<RoomItems> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Edit: becomes even more similar if you add mbj's using static directive.